# unordered map behavior in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, unordered-map

I have this 2 codes,

**Code 1**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<int,int>m;

    int nums[]={1,1,3,4,5};

    for(auto x:nums)
    {
        m[x]++;
    }

    for(auto x:m)
    {
        cout<<x.first<<" "<<m[x.first]<<endl;
    }

return 0;

}
```

**Code 2**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<int,int>m;

    int nums[]={1,1,3,4,5}; int k=2;

    for(auto x:nums)
    {
        m[x]++;
    }

    for(auto x:m)
    {
        cout<<x.first<<" "<<m[x.first+k]<<endl;
    }

return 0;

}
```

The output of the first code is

```
5 1
4 1
1 2
3 1
```

But the output of the second code is

```
5 0
4 0
5 0
7 0
```

I am not getting why the output of the 2nd code is like this, shouldn't it be like

```
5 0  //5 is the index and m[5+2]=0 hence 0
4 0  
1 1  //since m[1+2]=1 
3 1
```

......................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: The second code likely has UB because you're modifying the map (potentially invalidating the iterators) while iterating.

Comment: @mch giving the expected result, and being valid are two different things. The second code will result in undefined behavior in case of rehashing, so showing a compiler version of it that generates the expected result does not help much.

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) and [Why using namespace std is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721).

Answer (score 3):

When you do `m[x.first + k]`, you're modifying `m` when `x.first + k` is not already in `m`. According to [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at):

> If an insertion occurs and results in a rehashing of the container, all iterators are invalidated. [...]

If this occurs, you're invalidating iterators while iterating the map since `for (auto x: m)` is just a hidden way of iterating using iterators. Thus, your code has **undefined behavior** (you're using invalidated iterators), hence what you are seeing (and also why other people might see something different).

Answer (score 1):

operator[], on a map or unordered_map, has the potential to change the container, because (as you're relying on) when you call it with a key which isn't already present, it immediately adds it with a default-constructed value. As such, it's not safe to evaluate `m[foo]` while looping over `m` unless you're certain that `foo` is already present.

I'm not sure what this code is trying to do, but assuming it's just trying to print 0 when the value for the shifted key isn't present, you could do `unordered_map::find` directly on that shifted key and check whether the returned iterator is valid, and if not, print 0 instead.

Comment: It’s undefined behaviour therefore saying it “won’t crash” is wrong. See other answer.

Comment: `As such, it's not safe to evaluate m[foo] while looping over m unless you're certain that foo is already present.` I know that this is true for `unordered_map` because there an insert could invalidate all iterates if rehashing occurs. But you also mention `map`, but is it the case there too?

Comment: @t.niese Inserting into a `std::map` (via `insert`, `emplace` or `operator[]`) does not invalidate iterators.

Comment: @t.niese For `map` there's no UB, but you're likely to end up skipping later elements or revisiting earlier elements.